# How can I define "recursive" function type in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion, types, functional-programming, return

I have tasks, the task does something and returns True if it has to be called again.

```
function<bool()> currentAction;
```

I originally was going to go with something like this to manage my current task.

```
if (!currentAction())
    currentAction = []() { return false; };
```

Then I changed my mind and wanted something like this

```
currentAction = currentAction();
```

but what would be an appropriate type for CurrentAction?

it has to be a function that returns a function that returns a function that...

```
function<function<function<function<function<**[keep inserting here!]**()>()>()>()>()> currentAction;
```

**there is a decent chance that trying to do this is not a good idea**

Comment: Why don't you just run a while loop as long as the function returns true?

Comment: I'm not quite following. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Could you add more detail? @J.Schultke 's suggestion I think would be the simplest.

Comment: @J.Schultke The function is called once per second

Comment: Why did you change your mind? What benefit do you see in your new approach? (If there is no benefit, why wrestle with the syntax?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create class:

```
struct Action
{
    Action operator() { return next(); }

    std::function<Action()> next;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35a44cfd7a03a2b2)

Answer (score 1):

Expressing recursive types always involves a wrapper somewhere:

```
struct task : std::function<task()> { using std::function<task()>::function; };
```

But there's nothing wrong with them:

```
// "infinitely" recursive (UB when offset overflows, can use unsigned to make truly infinite)
task iota(int &out, int offset = 0) {
    return [&out, offset] {
        out = offset;
        return iota(out, offset + 1);
    };
}
```

Here's an example of a task that eventually "fails" (returns an empty `task`):

```
task limit(task t, int n) {
    if(n <= 0) return nullptr;
    else return [t = std::move(t), n]() { return limit(t(), n - 1); };
}
```

And here's how you might use them:

```
// prints integers [0, 42)
int main() {
    int i;
    task next = limit(iota(i), 42);
    while(next) {
        next = next();
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Running on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:23,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:23,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:23,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:23),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%0Astruct+task+:+std::function%3Ctask()%3E+%7B+using+std::function%3Ctask()%3E::function%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0Atask+iota(int+%26out,+int+offset+%3D+0)+%7B%0A++++return+%5B%26out,+offset%5D+%7B%0A++++++++out+%3D+offset%3B%0A++++++++return+iota(out,+offset+%2B+1)%3B%0A++++%7D%3B%0A%7D%0Atask+limit(task+t,+int+n)+%7B%0A++++if(n+%3C%3D+0)+return+nullptr%3B%0A++++else+return+%5Bt+%3D+std::move(t),+n%5D()+%7B+return+limit(t(),+n+-+1)%3B+%7D%3B%0A%7D%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++int+i%3B%0A++++task+next+%3D+limit(iota(i),+42)%3B%0A++++while(next)+%7B%0A++++++++next+%3D+next()%3B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+i+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:68.18515797207935,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:clang1001,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+10.0.1+Executor+(Editor+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:31.81484202792064,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)